# In react i am trying to render pages Using browserrouter and route but it does not render anything showing only blank screen here is my code

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

when I run react app on localhost it not showing any error but also not render anything and when I tried with only navbar component it render but same when I adds browserrouter it not shows anything I tried with exact path method also

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css';
import Navbars from './components/Navbar';

import Login from './components/screens/Login.jsx';
import Signup from './components/screens/Signup.jsx';

import Home from './components/screens/Home'
import Profile from './components/screens/Profile';




function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>

        <Navbars />
        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
            </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/signup">
          <Signup />
        </Route>

      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try wrapping all routes in a `<routes></routes>`
 component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your Routes in a `<Routes></Routes>` component. Also with `react-router-dom` V17 you have to use `element` prop instead of `component` like that:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
      // ... here your other routes
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the component prop with the component you want to render for each route.

You also have to wrap your routes like this.

Import Router and Switch too.

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route component={Register} exact path="/register"/>
    <Route component={Home} exact path="/" />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: showing same result

Comment: Check the new answer. Depending on the version you're using you may need to do as they answered.